# Ruby on Rails IMAP Show Mail Body Only Text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, imap

I am developing a mail application with Ruby on Rails, and I load inbox from an IMAP account.

This is the example of the body email that I got.

```
--f403043a82cc76a34c0563f3ab7c Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8" Yes, I can see it. On Jan 29, 2018 20:57, wrote: > Could you see this message? > --f403043a82cc76a34c0563f3ab7c Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8" Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Yes, I can see it.=C2=A0
=
```

My code looks like this :

```
<div id="Inbox" class="tabcontent todo-items tabdef">
  <% imap.select("INBOX") %>
  <% imap.search(["SINCE", "1-Feb-2018"]).each do |message_id| %>
    <% envelope = imap.fetch(message_id, "ENVELOPE")[0].attr["ENVELOPE"] %>
    <% msg = imap.fetch(message_id,'RFC822')[0].attr['RFC822'] %>
    <% mail = Mail.read_from_string msg %>
    <% body = imap.fetch(message_id,'BODY[TEXT]')[0].attr['BODY[TEXT]'] %>
    <div class="subject">
      <%= envelope.subject %>
    </div>
    <div class="message">
      <p><%= body.html_safe %></p>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I already using `html_safe` but not sure why that code is showing, in real inbox, those codes are not showing. It's show :

```
Yes, I can see it
```

Comment: Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable. When that's present you have to decode that part.

Comment: Where I need to put that?

Comment: You can't do all of that in a view. It's too complex. Send yourself a message with some text and an image, you'll see. Write a helper, or perhaps more than one.

Comment: Yes, but I mean, where I can hook the decoded? Since when I tried to decoded it, the 'body' already in string format.